# $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left[\lambda f\left(\frac{x}{2^k}\right)-f\left(\frac{x}{3\cdot 2^k}\right)\right]$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

Some time ago I saw a problem somewhere (I cannot remember where) that goes something like this. Let $f:[0,+\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a real function with $f(x)=f(\lfloor x\rfloor)$ for all $x\geq0$, $f(0)=0$ and such that $\exists\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}f(x)\neq0$. Can the following limit converge (in $\mathbb{R}$) for some constant $1\neq\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$?
$$\boxed{\lim_{x\to+\infty}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left[\lambda f\left(\frac{x}{2^k}\right)-f\left(\frac{x}{3\cdot 2^k}\right)\right]}$$
Note that the sum on the limit is actually finite as, given $x\geq0$, there exists $k_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall k\geq k_0:f(x/2^k)=f(x/(3\cdot2^k))=f(0)=0$. I have noticed that, if $f:[0,+\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies the above-mentioned hypotheses, then the limit $L = \lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\sum_{k=0}^\infty f\left(\frac{x}{2^k}\right)$ cannot exist since
$$\Rightarrow L = \lim_{x\to+\infty}\sum_{k=0}^\infty f\left(\frac{x/2}{2^k}\right) =\lim_{x\to+\infty}\sum_{k=0}^\infty f\left(\frac{x}{2^{k+1}}\right) =L-\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)\neq L$$
But it could so happen that the former limit exists (?).

In fact, if we denote $F(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty f\left(\frac{x}{2^{k+1}}\right)$, we can restate the troublesome condition as $\exists\lambda\neq1:\exists\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\lambda F(x)-F(x/3)$. Note that this condition of $F(x)$ alone can't imply the existence of $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}F(x)$ (and, thus, it can't lead us to a contradiction by itself) since for example, considering the [3-adic valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_valuation), we have for $\lambda\neq0$ that $F(x)=\lambda^{-\nu_3(\lfloor x\rfloor)}$ (with $F(x):=0$ for $\lfloor x\rfloor = 0$) is divergent while $\lambda F(3n)-F(n)=F(n)-F(n)=0$ which I think implies $\lambda F(x)-F(x/3)\to0$ (?). So it could still happen that $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\lambda F(x)-F(x/3)$ exists.

Comment: Oh , I was somehow fixated to read it as "fractional Part of x" , which is repeating. I see that I was wrong : It is "floor of x" , which is not repeating ! Thanks @aschepler I was totally wrong & you are right ! I got rid of all my wrong comments & I will rethink the question !

Comment: $\lim_{x \to +\infty} (\lambda F(x) - F(x/3)) = (\lambda-1) \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) \neq 0$. But this does not imply that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \sum (f(3x/2^k) - f(x/2^k))$ is $\pm \infty$ because we cannot reorder the terms in an infinite series which is not absolutely convergent. (Although the series is finite and therefore absolutely convergent at one particular $x$, the limit involves an unbounded number of non-zero terms.)

Comment: @aschepler With my notation, $F(x)\neq f(x)$. So, what do you mean by $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}(\lambda F(x)-F(x/3))=(\lambda-1)\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}f(x)$? I get that, if $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}F(x)$ existed, then $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}(\lambda F(x)-F(x/3))=(\lambda-1)\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}F(x)$. But, as I mentioned, with $F(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(x/2^k)$, it is impossible for $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} F(x)$ to exist. Also, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \lambda f(x/2^k)-f(x/(3\cdot 2^k))=\lambda F(x)-F(x/3)$ is true for every $x\geq0$.

Comment: Oops, the first part I wrote there doesn't make sense. I must have confused $f$ and $F$ at some point, knowing they're different. But I'm not following why you say $\exists \lim_{x \to +\infty} (\lambda F(x) - F(x/3))$.

Comment: @aschepler What I meant is that, if such an $f(x)$ existed, then the corresponding $F(x)$ would satisfy that $\exists \lambda\neq1$ such that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\lambda F(x)-F(x/3)$. It isn't actually a deduction but a rewriting of the troublesome condition. Sorry for the confusion: I have now clarified the question.

Comment: I'm not convinced that $\lim_{x \to +\infty}(\lambda F(x) - F(x/3))$ is the same as the original limit in question.

Comment: @aschepler Why not? It is true that
$$\forall x\geq0:\lambda F(x)-F(x/3)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\lambda f(x/2^k)-f(x/(3\cdot 2^k))$$
and so $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\lambda F(x)-F(x/3)$ is precisely the same limit. (Note that $F(x)$ is not an infinite series but a sum of variable unbounded but finite size)

Comment: When you put it that way, it's obvious, yes. I was stuck on imagining rearranging the sums "as a formula" before taking the limit, rather than rearranging the sums "independently at each $x$", if that makes sense.

Comment: On to something. I think for any such $f$, the limit exists if and only if $\lambda = \log_3(2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the limit cannot exist. Say $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x) = L$. Name the sum $g: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$:

$$ g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left[\lambda f\!\left(\frac{x}{2^k}\right) - f\!\left(\frac{x}{3 \cdot 2^k}\right)\right] $$

and suppose $\lim_{x \to +\infty} g(x) = M$.

Then for every positive $x$,

$$ g(2x) = \lambda f(2x) - f\!\left(\frac{2x}{3}\right) + g(x) $$

And then

$$ 0 = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \left[g(2x) - g(x) - \lambda f(2x) + f\!\left(\frac{2x}{3}\right)\right] = M - M + (\lambda - 1) L $$

So either $L=0$ or $\lambda=1$. It is not possible that $L \neq 0$ and $\lambda \neq 1$ and the limit of $g$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

These techniques below are very advanced and possibly not even useful for your problem. I'm posting this answer so that if someone else lands up on this page wondering "How on earth do I sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lambda f(\frac{x}{2^n}) - f(\frac{x}{3*2^n})$" for some arbitrary $f$ (say discovering this post via approach0) or something related that they can find this answer.

If we let the operator $O[f] = f(x/2)$  then if $g = \lambda f(x) + f(x/3)$   this series is really just

$$ g(x) + O[g(x)] + O^2[g(x)] + ... $$

I.E. $$ \frac{1}{1-O} [ g(x)] $$

in operator abuse of notation. By that same token if we let $O_{\ln} = x\frac{d}{dx}$ so for example $O_{\ln}[\ln(x)^3] = 3\ln(x)^2$ then we have that

$$ f\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = e^{-\ln(2) O_{\ln}} $$

Therefore:

$$ \frac{1}{1-O}  = \frac{1}{1-e^{-\ln(2)O_{\ln}}}$$

Now the function

$$ t(x) = \frac{1}{1-e^{-\ln(2)x}} = \frac{1}{\ln(2)} \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\ln(2)}{12 } x ... $$

Therefore:

$$ \frac{1}{1-e^{-\ln(2)O_{\ln}}} = \frac{1}{\ln(2)} O_{\ln}^{-1} + \frac{f(x)}{2} + \frac{\ln(2)}{12 } O_{\ln} - \frac{\ln(2)^3}{720} O_{\ln}^3 +... $$

I.E. to evaluate

$$ g(x) + g(x/2) + g(x/4) + ... $$ it suffices to look at

$$ \frac{1}{\ln(2)}  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{g(x)}{x} dx + \frac{g(\infty)-g(0)}{2} + \frac{\ln(2)}{12} (\infty g'(\infty) - 0*g'(0)) + \frac{\ln(2)^3}{720} (x(x(xg')')'|_{0}^{\infty}  ... $$

Where expressions like $\infty g'(\infty)$ and $0*g'(0)$ and $ (x(x(xg')')'|_{0}^{\infty} $  involve taking limits.